# Failure of Ujjwala Scheme (LPG subsidies) in India

Tags: india, social-welfare

Despite massive publicity, the Government of India's much-hyped [Ujjwala scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Give_up_LPG_subsidy#Pradhan_Mantri_Ujjwala_Yojana_Scheme) which had promised to wean away rural women from using wood as fuel in the kitchens has failed big time.

What are the reasons for the reluctance of rural women in Northern India to use cleaner fuels like LPG?

Reference:

[About 85% of Ujjwala beneficiaries in four States still use earthen stoves](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/about-85-of-ujjwala-beneficiaries-in-four-states-still-use-earthen-stoves/article26763409.ece)

[About the Ujjwala scheme](http://vikaspedia.in/energy/policy-support/pradhan-mantri-ujjwala-yojana)

Comment: This looks like economic question than a political one.

Comment: People like to use what they're familiar with.